# Angular ng-click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have these functions:

```
$scope.addProduct = function($event, obj) {

    var myEl = angular.element($event.target);

    myEl.parent().html('<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="removeProduct('+ obj.id +')">Remove from Widget</button>');

};

$scope.removeProduct = function(id) {
    console.log('Remove ->' + id);

};
```

When I click on "addProduct" it work but when I click on "removeProduct" does not work. Looks like it doesn't listen the click on the new button that I added. How can I solve it?

Comment: adding html the jquery way won't make angular bindings work. You'll have to re-think your whole code and code it more angular-friendly with a directive/template. please provide a jsfiddle to help you more.

Comment: I think you have completely right! I'll create a directive for that, it's the best solution. Thanks man.

Comment: by the way, I think the todo tutorial of angularjs.org homepage would really help you :p : http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

Comment: Maybe you don't even need a directive. Have both buttons in your template and play with their visibility (`ng-show` or `ng-if`). Have a boolean variable like `$scope.viewState.productAdded` to control which button is visible.

Answer (score 1):

In order for `ngClick` to take effect, you need to first compile your HTML and link it to the `$scope`:

```
.controller('someCtrl', function ($compile, $scope) {
    ...

    $scope.addProduct = function($event, obj) {
        var myEl = angular.element($event.target);
        var myBtn = $compile('<button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="removeProduct('+ obj.id +')">Remove from Widget</button>')($scope);
        myEl.after(myBtn);
    };

    $scope.removeProduct = function(id) {
        console.log('Remove ->' + id);
    };
});
```

---

**UPDATE:**

**[Kos Prov's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24054730/angular-ng-click-event/24054864#comment-37089221)** is very true - sometimes you think about solving the problem, but you don't think the question was wrong in the first place.

So, of course manipulating the DOM should be a directive's responsibility, so I created a directive to do what you want (according to your question):

app.directive('removableProduct', function ($compile) {
        var btnTmpl = 
            '' +
                'Remove from Widget' +
            '';

```
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {item: '='},
        template: '<div ng-click="addProduct($event)">{{item.description}}</div>',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.addProduct = function (evt) {
                var myEl = angular.element(evt.target);
                var myBtn = $compile(btnTmpl)($scope);
                myEl.after(myBtn);
            };
            $scope.removeProduct = function(id) {
                console.log('Remove -> ' + id);
            };
        }
    };
});
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/es593/)**.

Comment: This fixes the problem but it's like the worst possible Angular code that could ever exist. Promoting ugly quick fixes is not good for the community.

Comment: @KosProv: My excuses to the community :) I updated my answer. Thx for the heads-up - I hope the damage done to the community was not permanent :P

Comment: Fear not my friend. The protector of the community is here (that's me, yeah :P). Now, seriously: the class of "I come from jQuery, the natural thing to do is this, why doesn't it work?" errors are increasing. I even saw a completed project that all controllers where like `$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() { /* jQuery DOM manipulation here */})`. Personally, I prefer to comment that this is bad design than trying to fix it. I removed my downvote and my apologies if I was a bit harse.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean :) Sometimes I focus on solving the "problem" that I don't see the actual problem (although looking back I feel bad for letting something so obviously non-Angularish slip through). Thank you for watching over us :P

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem which should not exist if you do it in Angular way.

For every product try to hold a boolean value like 'productAdded' in your $scope model.

Then you can do in example:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products">
    <button ng-show="product.productAdded" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="addProduct(product)">Add to Widget</button>
    <button ng-show="!product.productAdded" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="removeProduct(product.id)">Remove from Widget</button>
</div>
```

Hope this clarifies a bit for you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a remove button after a product is added, you should add the remove button within the ng-repeat itself:

**JS**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
   <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="product in products">
           {{product.name }}<button ng-click="deleteProduct(product)">Delete</button>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.products = [{ name:'pencil' }, { name: 'crayon' }, { name: 'pen' }];
    $scope.deleteProduct = function(product) {
        var index = $scope.products.indexOf(product);
        if (index >=0) {
            // remove the product
            $scope.products.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
});
```